# Value Oriented Programming Languages

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, immutability

In this greak talk [Value of Values](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6BsiVyC1kMQ), Rich talks about Place Oriented Programming (PLOP) which mutates data in place, lets call the languages with everything immutable or values as Value Oriented Programming (VLOP) for a moment. What languages other than Clojure are VLOP and how they implemented immutability (e.g. Structural Sharing, Plain Copy etc.) ?

Comment: You can do VLOP in any programming language by being disciplined. All pure functional languages are VLOP based

Comment: In practice, though, it requires things like proper closures, tail-call optimisation, and GC, otherwise you won't be very productive.

Answer (score 3):

"Value-oriented programming" is, more or less, just an alternative name for functional programming. For example, see [here (1998)](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/331/spring03/0101/lectures/fininfp.ppt) or [here (2004)](http://books.google.de/books?id=568u_k1R4lUC&pg=PA579&lpg=PA579&dq=%22value-oriented%20programming%22%20functional&source=bl&ots=XsPKzPPcWQ&sig=cSSflDrAIkTZ-p6Qdf2kNf812hE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NzULU-DzNceP7AbC_YC4BA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22value-oriented%20programming%22%20functional&f=false), and most prominently, Andrew Appel's 1995 talk "Value-oriented programming, not object-oriented programming!" (which I cannot find online). The actual term can be traced back to [at least 1981](https://archive.org/details/valuesobjectsinp00macl).

Unfortunately, the name never caught on, although Appel and other people have argued in the past that it is more accurate (and perhaps also more buzzword-compliant), and would have made functional programming an easier sell.

In other words, you are just looking for functional languages, of which there are many. Most famously, Haskell, ML (Ocaml and SML), Scheme.